# Networking indicator missing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

Networking indicator missing in Ubuntu 14.04

When I update my system and then restart, my system network indicator is not shown in unity panel.

I try to edit: `Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet` in `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` but it does not help.

Is there any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Does it appear if you type in a terminal

```
nm-applet
```

In this case the applet will run until you close the terminal.

If it appears it could be an autostart problem.